# What do I call the window in the warehouse which is used to submit kitted goods to the customer?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, translation

I'm translating a text about a warehousing system inside a company. There is a window inside the warehouse through which the person (say, from a production department) may collect the goods and/or materials kitted on his order (see "[order picking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_picking)"), and then go and use these in his production department.

What do I call this window? In Russian it is the "**hand-over window**" (окно выдачи). Or "hand-out window".

> The conveyors are equipped with the necessary quantity of geared motors, chains, rollers, bearings, photoelectric retro-reflective sensors, circuit breakers, thermal switches etc. to ensure the safe transportation of items in pallets or in boxes loaded on pallets to the **hand-over window**.

Comment: do you mean "knitted goods"? Is it a window or a platform? Loading platform or loading dock come to mind. Window in English implies a hole in the wall of a building or a partition. Delivery window, if it is indeed a window.

Comment: @Lambie - "kitted" or "collated" goods - it's when different inventory items are taken from different parts of the warehouse and bundled into a... kit (?) which is handed over to the worker. I found that "kitting" is a term used in the warehousing business.

Comment: In Britain I think it would be the "stores collection window", or "the stores pick-up window". Americans don't use "stores" in quite this way. They are more inclined to talk about the "warehouse". In Britain a "warehouse" usually suggests a separate building, or very large facility.

Comment: @WS2 - thank you! I like "pick-up window".

Comment: Things coming off production lines are not stores, even in Britain. They are output or production or widgets. As I asked and was not given an answer about, is this really a WINDOW or is it a platform?? I would be most surprised if this were an actual window. It's items ON pallets. What is the actual movement? Conveyor belt to pallet to? Pallets usually sit on the floor or loading dock. No windows. Loading docks have roll-up doors.

Comment: Pick-up window sounds like a retail shop or store. It does not sound industrial at all. For mass produced goods. I mean, are you kidding? They are passing goods through a window? Imagine the weight....Haven't you seen a roll-up door on a loading dock where pallets are WHEELED OUT on a pallet truck or warehousing truck.

Comment: rewrite: ensure items on pallets or in boxes loaded on pallets may be safely moved to the X. Not transported here.

Comment: @Lambie - yes, this "window" might be figurative, but maybe the window is used for paperwork and the pallet is moved beside the window using a door. Who knows. Translators are not often given explanations by the authors..

Comment: @Lambie well the OP says the window is in a "warehouse".

Comment: The window might be figurative?? Are you a Russian speaker translating into English? Because I can tell you flat out, given your sentence, which is about conveyor belts and getting goods to the loading place, pick-up window is probably wrong. The inside of production plants don't usually have pick-up "windows".

Comment: It's just a *window*, *counter*, or *booth*. An adjective, usually referring to its specific purpose, specifies it: *complaint window*, *ticket booth*, *pickup counter*, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fellow translator told me of the term **goods issue** used in warehousing, and I think that this "window" may be called **goods issue point** or **goods issue hall** or **goods issue window**:

> From "*Logistic Core Operations with SAP: Inventory Management, Warehousing*" by Jens Kappauf, Bernd Lauterbach, Matthias Koch ([Google Books link](https://books.google.ru/books?id=NUvc73bKANkC&lpg=PA143&ots=d245l35Kr0&dq=warehouse%20%22goods%20issue%22&hl=ru&pg=PA143#v=onepage&q&f=false)):
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

"Supply" is often used in processes where goods are given out.
A point or place like the window in your example, or a desk is also called 
counter. So, you could call it supply-counter or supply counter window.

Comment: Or *supply-point*.

Answer (score 0):

I am certain that 'hand-over window' is a local term within a single company and there exists no widely used equivalent, generally, in industry.

Every sizeable company I can think of that I have ever known or have ever dealt with has a 'Goods In' and a 'Goods Out'. Raw materials in and finished product out. This is not an internal matter but the In/Out relates to In and Out regarding the outside world beyond the company premises.

But companies and their functions - and the individual ways in which companies organise themselves - are so hugely varied that there exists, to my knowledge and as far as I have scoured the internet, no commonly used term of the kind that is being sought.

Comment: "Goods out" is from the factory to customers, not for internel use?

Comment: @WeatherVane Just edited to make it clearer.

Comment: OP made it clear that a **hand-over window** is a translation from the Russian term in use, if that is "local" ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, but it is translated 'inside a company'. My understanding is that the OP has translated the document of a single company and my understanding is that the methodology relates to that single company.It is that single company's word for what that single company has set up within their own company. That is what I mean by 'local'.

Answer (score 0):

A **window** does not describe a location where a pallet may be handed over.

I suggest **stores** which is a managed repository of goods for internal use.

> Get your equipment from the stores.

In the military, the person in charge of such stores is called a quartermaster.